# mysqli_stmt::bind_param() error

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a more my class for database management, and I just hit a snag. I have basic interactions with phpMyAdmin, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`, etc...

While running the `update` function I run into the problem:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in **C:\xampp\htdocs\page\assets\class.database.php** on line **253**

I have been attempting to debug it, and I am not sure why the params are not being counted correctly. This is the code that is running into issues:

```
if ($stmt = $this->_connection->prepare( $sql ))
{
    $stmt->bind_param($stmt_param, ...$val); /* line 253 */
    $stmt->execute();
    // ... more code ... //
}
```

`$stmt_param` is built:

```
// bind params
$stmt_param = str_repeat('s', $array_num);
$add_id = 'i';
$stmt_param = substr($stmt_param, 0, -1).$add_id;
```

`$val` is built

```
foreach($content_array as $key => $value)
{
    $val[] = $value;
}
```

`$sql` is built

```
/* $table == TABLE_NAME */
/* $table_rows == KEY_VALUES_FROM_ARRAY */
$sql = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET " . $table_rows . " WHERE id = ?";
```

To call the function I have three params:

```
/*
 * @param $id will determine the unique record
 * @param $content_array an array setup `Column => Value`
 * @param $table which table to query
 */
public function update( $id, $content_array, $table )
```

So the code would look like:

```
$update = $db->update('7' /* unique id */,
                      array('complete' => '1') /* array with column => value */,
                      'player' /* table name */);
```

I am not sure which part of this code is not correct, I have a very similar function for `insert` and it works flawlessly, I have been troubleshooting, but nothing has helped.

For full class, the code is on [Github](https://github.com/brazucaz/php_database/blob/master/src/class.database.php). I wanted to localize the question to my problem.

Comment: where is `$sql` ?

Comment: So why instead of providing start to end function code you show us some parts of it?

Comment: @Ravi I have updated my answer

Comment: @u_mulder it's on [Github](https://github.com/brazucaz/php_database/blob/master/src/class.database.php)

Comment: @Samuel I don't know, if anyone can answer your question, the way you are posting part of code.

Comment: Then output your `$sql` to see what is generated.

Comment: `$sql` is fine: `UPDATE player SET complete = ? WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Next - `$stmt_param`?

Comment: @Ravi I didn't want to post the entire function on the here, it's quite long.

Comment: @u_mulder `$stmt_param == 'si' `

Comment: And finally - `$val`.

Comment: @u_mulder `$val == Array( [0] => 1 )`

Comment: You are adding the parameter for the `id` parameter into the `$val` array before the update.

Comment: So, you have __two__ placeholders, but __one__ value. Isn't it strange, huh?

Comment: @u_mulder, right.. I need the `$id` on there...... -_-

Comment: So, could you do all the above __without__ me?

Comment: @u_mulder you mean the troubleshooting?

Comment: I mean debugging, yes.

Comment: Perhaps, I've had better days... I did get those values before, but for some reason it wasn't clicking with me what the problem was.